# What tense and sentence structure is used?

Tags: tenses, syntactic-analysis

Below line is an excerpt from *The Hindu* newspaper.

> Many have been quick to conclude that it was his strong anti-Russia position that led to Rex Tillerson's dismissal as U.S. Secretary of state by President Donald Trump on March 13.

1. What tense is used here? if it is present perfect continuous, then the verb *conclude* is not in present participle form. Why so?
2. What type of sentence structure is applied here?

Comment: Thanks @BillJ . Now i understand. you can post this as answer itself.

Comment: Done! Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Many have been quick to conclude that it was his strong anti-Russia position that led to Rex Tillerson's dismissal as U.S.Secretary of state by President Donald Trump on March 13.*

The matrix tense is present perfect: "have been ... ."

"Conclude" is a plain form verb heading the infinitival clause "to conclude that ... ." which functions as complement of "quick".

Syntactically, the sentence has the form of a declarative clause